# Running Matlab GUI from C#

Tags: c#, matlab, user-interface

In my project, I am integrating Matlab GUI application with in a C# application.

The solution I thought about is to create a standalone application from the Matlab GUI and start it via a button in C#:

```
Process exeProcess = Process.Start("Data_Capture_Direct_call.exe");
        if(!exeProcess.HasExited)
        {
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
        exeProcess.Close();
```

The problem is that after the splash screen of Matlab GUI is closed and before the actual program opens, C# detects that the program has been closed already and carries on to the next line.

In addition, the next few lines of code are not properly executed:

```
List<String> Movement = new List<String>();
        List<String> Repetition = new List<String>();
        List<String> Duration = new List<String>();
        using (CsvFileReader reader = new CsvFileReader("capture.csv"))
        {
            CsvRow row = new CsvRow();
            while (reader.ReadRow(row))
            {
                Movement.Add(row[0]);
                Repetition.Add(row[1]);
                Duration.Add(row[2]);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < Movement.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, Movement[i], Repetition[i], Duration[i]);
        }
```

What happens is that after the C# wrongly detects closure of the process, the capture.csv file becomes empty and data is not loaded into the data grid.

Please let me know where I am making a mistake or if there is a better way to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my solution you should do some settings before starting code in order to use Matlab instance in a C# application.

Adding neccessary dll : 
 First we will add dll reference with COM interface. Click RMB on project and choose [Add Reference]  option. In new window click COM tab. In search text box write 'Matlab'. Then choose "Matlab Application (Version 7.10) Type Library".

You should get references like below :

[image]

Now you can easily do whatever you can do on Matlab in C# . Lets give an basic example :

```
        var acCtx = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("matlab.application.single"); 
        var matlab = (MLApp.MLApp)Activator.CreateInstance(acCtx);
```

these two lines are creating of matlab instance in code.Now let's make a easy computation on Matlab.

```
       Console.WriteLine(matlab.Execute("1+2")); // This will output 3 on console.
       matlab.Quit(); // you should close matlab in order to clean memory
```

Lets give solution to your actual problem.You want to execute a Matlab GUI program.And I think your Gui is recording some data to CSV file.Then your C# program processes that data.You should note that you can call your GUI in Matlab just writing your name of program as command.Suppose that you have a GUI called myGui.m.You can call that gui by calling myGui in command line as you can write 1+2 to get 3.

Let's call gui.

```
matlab.Execute("myGui"); // This will execute your Gui. You can use buttons to save data to CSV file
  matlab.Quit();
```

I have extended example on this page : 
[Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594636/Using-Matlab-from-a-Csharp-application)

Comment: Thank you for you complete answer.
It is much easier for me to just call for the my Matlab GUI, since it is a complex GUI and it take lots of effort to convert all.
However, the problem is after I placed the my GUI files (.m .fig ) in the debug folder and run as you mentioned matlab will open in taskbar (no window) and closes after a few second.

Comment: You don't need to put any matlab files to your debug folder.All of them should be in Matlab current folder. If it is not working maybe your m files of gui are not on Matlabs current folder.